# Why this gross salary function returning 0?

Tags: c++

> Write a program to
>
> -> create a class “employee” with data member as name, designation, and basic salary and gross salary.
>
> -> Create member functions as function getdata to read and function showdata to display details.
>
> -> Create sum() as friend function to calculate gross salary.
>
> BS=basic_salary
>   gs = basic_salary + 0.5 * basic_salary + 0.9 * basic_salary;

There's something wrong in my code. The get_gs() function is always returning 0. What is my error?

I have made it run again after deleting the previous .exe too, asumming compiler error. But it remains the same.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class employee 
{
    string name;
    string designation;
    double bs;
    double gs;

public:
    employee()
    {
    }

    employee(string _name, string des, double _bs)
    {
        name = _name;
        designation = des;
        bs = _bs;
    }

    void set(string _name, string des, double _bs)
    {
        employee(_name, des, _bs);
    }

    double get_gs()
    {
        double gs;
        gs=bs + (0.5 * bs) + (0.9 * bs);
        return gs;
    }
};

int main()
{
    employee *e = new employee;
    string name, desti;
    double bs, gs;
    cout << "Enter name destiny basic_salary  " << endl;
    cin >> name >> desti >> bs;
    e->set(name, desti, bs);
    gs=e->get_gs();
    cout << "the Gross salary :" << gs << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `employee(_name,des,_bs);` is practically a NOP. You should set your member variables there instead.

Comment: Why `employee *e = new employee;` instead of `employee e;`? You don't `delete` allocated `employee` either. Or, why do you create it, when you don't know the construction arguments, when you can, just as easily create it, after you read everything: `employee e (name, desti, bs);`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solution with comments in the code:

```
#include <iostream>
// using namespace std; // not a good practise
class employee {
    std::string name;
    std::string designation;
    double bs;
    // double gs; // wasn't used so remove it

public:
    // initialize values like this, and pass strings as "const&":
    employee(const std::string& _name, const std::string& des, double _bs) :
        name(_name), designation(des), bs(_bs)
    {}

    employee() : employee("", "", 0) {} // delegate to first constructor

    void set(const std::string& _name, const std::string des&, double _bs) {
        // your old set() created a temporary employee that
        // wasn't used for anything and then it was destroyed
        name = _name;
        designation = des;
        bs = _bs;
    }
    // make member functions that does not change the state of "this" const
    double get_gs() const { return bs + (0.5 * bs) + (0.9 * bs); }
};

int main() {
    employee e; // no need for new, create it like any other variable
    std::string name, desti;
    double bs, gs;
    std::cout << "Enter name destiny basic_salary\n";
    std::cin >> name >> desti >> bs;
    e.set(name, desti, bs);
    gs = e.get_gs();
    std::cout << "the Gross salary : " << gs << "\n";
}
```

Answer (score 3):

In your `set()` method, calling `employee(_name, des, _bs);` creates a new temporary `employee` object that is then immediately discarded. It does not update the members of the `employee` object that `set()` is called on, like you are expecting. As such, the `bs` member is never being assigned a value.

Try this instead:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class employee
{
    string name;
    string designation;
    double bs;

public:
    employee() : bs(0.0) { }

    employee(string _name, string des, double _bs)
        : name(_name), designation(des), bs(_bs)
    {
    }

    void set(string _name, string des, double _bs)
    {
        name = _name;
        designation = des;
        bs = _bs;
    }

    double get_gs() const
    {
        return bs + (0.5 * bs) + (0.9 * bs);
    }
};

int main()
{
    employee e;
    string name, desti;
    double bs, gs;
    cout << "Enter name destiny basic_salary " << endl;
    cin >> name >> desti >> bs;
    e.set(name, desti, bs);
    gs = e.get_gs();
    cout << "the Gross salary :" << gs << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Alternatively:

```cpp
int main()
{
    string name, desti;
    double bs, gs;
    cout << "Enter name destiny basic_salary " << endl;
    cin >> name >> desti >> bs;
    employee e(name, desti, bs);
    gs = e.get_gs();
    cout << "the Gross salary :" << gs << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It's a good thing to pass string-by-value in the setter, as along as `designation = std::move(des);` is used.